# Why are my static prototype UITableViewCells from Storyboard showing up blank?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I defined the static prototype UITableCells, subclasses, outlets, etc. in the storyboard, but when I run the app and go to that viewcontroller/scene, the cells are there, but they have no content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up a table view with static prototype cells in Storyboards, you do so by having dragged out a UITableViewController and then subclassing it.

The trouble is that UITableViewController is oh so helpful and supplies datasource methods for you to override.

Force of habit had me getting in there and supplying default implementations for those datasource methods.

Turns out that not only do you NOT have to supply datasource methods, but if you do, they *interfere* with proper display of static prototype cells.  I just commented out all of the datasource methods in my viewcontroller and everything started displaying fine.